# Creating a grid of buttons with tkinter and asking the user to choose specific buttons

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter

I'm trying to create a program that creates a grid of buttons, and then asks the user to select specific buttons.

If the user chooses the correct button then that button is disabled and the program asks the user for another random button until the entire grid is filled. If the user chooses the wrong button then nothing happens (Or perhaps an error label shows up).

My line of thought is that I'll create a class as below where each button has a row and column attribute and when a button is clicked it calls a function that compares the current buttons row and column with the required row and column.

```
from tkinter import *

class gridButtons():
def __init__(self,rowPosition, colPosition,masterFrame):
    self.rowPosition = rowPosition
    self.colPosition = colPosition

    self.button = Button(masterFrame,text = str(self.colPosition)+","+str(self.rowPosition),command = self.checkButtonPos,width=5)
    self.button.grid(row = self.rowPosition,column = self.colPosition,padx=3, pady=3)

root = Tk()
buttonFrame = Frame(root)
buttonFrame.pack()

buttonList = []
for r in range(10):
    for c in range(10):
        buttonToCreate = gridButtons(r,c,buttonFrame)
        buttonList.append(buttonToCreate)
root.mainloop()
```

My primary question is how I should think about creating the checkButtonPos command. Let us say that we want the user to press the button with coordinates (row 3, column 4) the first time and if that button is pressed a new coordinate comes up until all buttons have been clicked. I was thinking something like the following:

```
def checkButtonPos(requiredRow,requiredCol):
    buttonColPosition = self.colPosition
    buttonRowPosition = self.rowPosition

    if buttonColPosition == requiredCol and buttonRowPosition == requiredRow:
        self.config(text = "Yes",state = DISABLED)
```

I'm uncertain how I would change the requiredRow and requiredCol everytime the user chooses the correct button.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can bake arguments into the command function with `functools.partial`.

```
from functools import partial
self.button = Button(command = partial(self.checkButtonPos, rowPosition, colPosition))
```

This means when the button is pressed it passes the row and column as arguments. In other words clicking the button runs `self.checkButtonPos(rowPosition, colPosition)` (instead of just `self.checkButtonPos()`).

As an aside, I'm glad you are learning about classes, but in this case the class adds no value.